# Why do rechargeable batteries have no short-curcuit protection?

Tags: batteries, safety, short-circuit

Whenever I read a user manual to a device that runs off a rechargeable battery - like a cell phone or a power driver - the manual will always say I should store and handle the battery in such way that its terminals are not shorted by any objects like a paper clip or a screwdriver or any other stuff I might have in my pocket or bag. The warning further says shorting may lead to a battery exploding.

Why won't batteries have circuitry that addresses shorting and makes it less dangerous?

Comment: My idea that there should be one, but the manufacturer must still warn the user about possible wrong usage and consequences, also to be legally covered in case this happens.

Comment: @clabacchio, that is what I know to be true. They have protection, but they warn you to make sure they are covered.

Comment: @Kortuk -- they don't always have protection. Store-bought rechargeable NiMH ones don't.

Comment: AFAIK there is no space left for any protections in those small NiHM batteries. It would eat a lot of capacity. There's just chemistry, no circuitry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two main types of rechargeable batteries - Lithium Ion and its children (such as LiPo) and the rest.

- LiIon cells MUST ALWAYS have protection electronics and the vast majority do have. If abused or, sometimes, just because it wants to, a LiIon cell will reduce both itself and the equipment it is in to a flaming heap.

**LiIon "Vent with flame" ...** - spontaneous "uncaused" laptop self dismantlement because (even) Sony could not get it right.

[image]

The no-name brand can't always either ;-) ...

[image]

---

- All other types **can** cause serious damage when shorted but are not usually prone to explosive self dismantlement. Short-circuiting may cause dangerously high thermal energy dissipation and may damage the cells permanently, but will generally not cause a run-away reaction.

LiIon (Lithium Ion) is a "slow release bomb" waiting to happen. A LiIon battery may be able to be persuaded to "vent with flame" (Gargoyle knows) by charging too fast, charging to excessive voltage, heavy discharge, spike penetration or heavy knock, charging at normal rate when voltage is low, charging at all when voltage is very low.

Protection devices for LiIon calls are the norm. These usually mount **INSIDE** the battery casing so their presence is not obvious. LiIon cells should ALWAYS use such devices. Most manufacturers will not sell LiIon cells without internal protection devices. Some will.

LiIon cells under fault conditions undergo heavy self discharge at a point which produces Hydrogen gas and first molten and then gaseous lithium metal. Temperatures rapidly rise to the ignition point "and away it goes". Once started  the reaction usually runs to completion. Water is welcomed as an additional reactant by the Lithium metal.

[Lithium ion safety](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/lithium_ion_safety_concerns)

---

Lead Acid, NimH. NiCd, NiFe, LiFePO4 ...

can all do significant thermal damage and will probably damage the cells if you short them and leave them shorted. BUT they usually do not explode and are not usually known to self incinerate.

**I have never seen any of these batteries fitted with internal protection.**

Note that LiFePO4 = Lithium Ferro phosphate, is in that list. A LiFePO4 cell is about as safe as they come. You can drive a silver spike through its heart, if you must. It will not thank you, but also will not self dismantle. Very briefly, the reason is that the Li metal is held in a spinel structure in the cell proper and does not migrate physically when the going gets exciting.

A lead acid "car battery" will melt about anything metallic that you place across its terminals. This would include eg large crescent wrenches. If you got badly hurt by bits of molten wrench you should not be surprised. The battery would probably never be the same again, but will probably not melt down.  You CAN literally explode a lead acid battery by igniting hydrogen generated during charging, but that is a separate issue.

Add say 6 x AA Nimh 2000+ mAh cells, various coins and some keys to a trouser pocket and go about your business. On occasion you will get a short via coins and keys and misc cells so hot that skin burns could result and fire would not be a surprise. If you manage to do this you are an idiot! I've done it two or three times :-). Not again, I think!!!

NiCd about as for Nimh. More robust against shorts probably.

A fully charged 2000+ mAh AA Nimh will provide 10+ amps into a hard short.

Comment: The detail is good and worthwhile, but a short form answer would be: because any money, space, weight, or series resistance spent or accepted from protective devices isn't producing or storing useful energy, manufacturers of any type of battery don't want to include more than is necessary to prevent the battery from creating a hazard via means other than its design behavior (outputting current at its specified voltage).  If wires connected to a car battery short-circuit and catch fire, that won't be the fault of the battery, which would simply be outputting current *as designed*.

Comment: By contrast, if a laptop battery bursts into flames, the damage it might do to persons and property would be a consequence of non-specified behavior.  It's interesting to note that some types of smaller batteries lack protective devices found in bigger ones.  Small watch batteries can explode if overheated, for example, but things like AAA or larger cells will leak instead.  I think the thinking is that if a battery is small enough, there's limit to how much damage it will do if it explodes.

Comment: @supercat - That is an answer but not directly a summary of mine. I essentially said that LiIon NED protectionand MOST have it built in. I said that other typs do not need protection in the waay that liIon do and manufacturers do not build it in. I said little or nothing about cost drivers and I don't think they are the main issue. All bar LiIon do not have them because they are not generall needed.

Comment: When you say internal protection, you seem to be talking about bare cells, while the OP seems to be talking about battery packs.  Bare cells can have basic protection integrated directly into them, like a PTC fuse or meltable separator, while a pack might have a more elaborate circuit.  Some of these mechanisms are reversible when the short goes away and some are not.  If a reversible one is tripped, even if the pack still works afterward, it may have driven high current for at least milliseconds and suffered some damage that will show up later as lower cycle life or worse.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon could you please elaborate on what types of protection circuits you are seeing inside modern Li-ion or LiPo battery packs.  How complex do they get in cheaper products like cameras.  Do any of them refuse to put out current unless they can talk to the host device on a separate pin, or is the crypto stuff in some laptops more a matter of the host refusing to charge "counterfeit" packs.  I can post a separate question if you like.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: Sometimes I find it useful to have answers which begin with a very brief summary (though I then went on in my comment to suggest something that would be a bit too long for such purpose--oh well).  Short-circuit damages battery--acceptable.  Battery blows supplies enough current to blow something up--acceptable.  Battery bursts into flames and burns down an orphanage killing everyone inside--not acceptable.  Manufacturers add protection to guard against unacceptable risks--not acceptable ones.

Answer (score 4):

An ideal battery is good if it has the lowest inner resistence.
Any additional circuit is a waste of energy. The resistence will rise by such a protective circuit.

The application has to decide wether to waste the energy or not, not the battery manufacturer.

LiPo(...) cell have a strange behaviour. Under sometimes unpredictable circumstances a cell overheats in seconds. 
There is a new testing method developed that works with a weak altering current that measures this change and temperature rise inside the cell. This is very complicated at the moment.

I think in the future integrated circuit will be added to all LiPo's to prevent hazards. But at the moment the price is the only force that keep this from the mass market.